UNNEST several arrays PostgreSQL 15
I have a problem:
in my code I need to convert several columns into a table.
I have 3 columns:

I need to convert it into

I tried to use string_to_array and unnest() like:
SELECT UNNEST(string_to_array(pdate), string_to_array(stage), string_to_array(amount)) FROM table

But I get an error message:
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function unnest(text[], text[], text[]) does not exist


It is slightly more complicated: you have to "unnest" each array and join the resulting tables by the index in the array:
SELECT dates.pdate,
       stages.stage,
       amounts.amount
FROM unnest(pdate) WITH ORDINALITY AS dates(pdate, n)
   JOIN unnest(stage) WITH ORDINALITY AS stages(stage, n) USING (n)
   JOIN unnest(amount) WITH ORDINALITY AS amounts(amount, n) USING (n);

